# JLabel setLocation and setBounds methods not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, setbounds

First of all, I am well aware of the existence of Layout Managers, I just don't want to use it in this case.

I'm writing a simple main menu for my application, but no matter what I do the Image (`JLabel`) always sets itself in left upper corner of screen. I've tried using both methods (`setLocation`, `setBounds`), but it does not make any difference.

I'm sure it is some stupid mistake, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame{

    protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path,
                                        String description) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    Main() {
        ImageIcon image1=createImageIcon("/monopoly.jpg","");
        JLabel image1l=new JLabel(image1);
        image1l.setLocation(200,200);
        image1l.setBounds(330, 300, 140, 60);
        add(image1l);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main f=new Main();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.pack();
        f.setTitle("Monopoly");
        f.setSize(800,800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setLayout(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: you  can try to remove f.pack() if that works

Comment: `pack` layouts the components according default LayoutManager since the `setLayout` call is not yet executed - since no manager is required, no reason to call `pack`.

Comment: Note: IMO `setLayout` should be moved inside the constructor, more part of the class, like adding image/label

Comment: You're going to regret naming variables with a one and a lower case L.  The characters look too much alike.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP does not wish to use the clear path to a solution (layout managers).